# Why can RF learn multiplicative interaction but not additive interaction

Tags: random-forest, interaction

The answer to the post [Including Interaction Terms in Random Forest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157665/including-interaction-terms-in-random-forest?rq=1) shows how a random forest can learn a multiplicative interactive term without it being specified as a feature. On the other hand, I read in ESL that tree-based models cannot learn linear combinations of features that are not pre-specified. Can someone explain why a RF is able to learn multiplicative interaction but not additive interaction?

Comment: Where in ESL can we find that passage?

Comment: Some table in Section 10.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two arguments have competing definitions of "learn."  A random forest can approximate a functional form with additive and multiplicative interaction terms, but it cannot reproduce either exactly, and will have a particularly hard time approximating the function outside the range of inputs provided during training.

As a comment to the accepted answer in the linked question alludes ([reference link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s12859-016-0995-8)), even the approximation on the training range is subject to caveats.  [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/61279/55122) I play around with XOR style interactions, and among other things show that when other effects are being modeled, the trees may get distracted from faithfully representing the interaction.

Comment: No, I mean when the XOR is not the only part of the target; when the model is e.g. $x_1 + x_2 + sign(x_3 \cdot x_4)$, the trees may spend more time splitting on $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that they only occasionally find the xor structure in $x_3, x_4$.